# How to use a colliding namespace within a library

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have a structure similar to this for my packages:

```
top/
├── __init__.py
└── io
    └── __init__.py
```

Now I have this problem importing the standard library `urllib3.filepost`:

```
gonvaled@pegasus ~/top » python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan 11 2013, 17:58:01) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib3.filepost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-wavilon1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-wavilon1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-wavilon1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-wavilon1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 11, in <module>
    from io import BytesIO
ImportError: cannot import name BytesIO
```

Why is the standard library looking in `top.io`? How can I avoid this? I would really like to use `top.io` for my package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is *not* looking in `top.io`.

Instead, Python is looking in the *current directory*. The current directory is the first location in the `sys.path` list of locations to look for an import. The file `io.py` is in your local directory.

Never run your python interpreter *inside* of your package (so make sure the current working directory is not in `top`), and otherwise never name a local module that has the same name as a standard library.

Comment: But will @gonvaled be OK when his library is used as such and he doesn't have the interpreter running in his `top` directory?

Comment: @MartinStone: Yup, not running inside `top` means he'll be okay. Expanded.